# How to flatten one element within a list of lists in R

Tags: r, list, flatten

I see that there may be some questions somewhat related to this topic, but I want to ask it in a simple example.  I have a list of list, and I would like to flatten one of the lists so that it's components are at the same level as the other lists.  Consider the following simplified example:

```
library(tidyverse)

bb <- list(3,5)
names(bb) <-  c("L1", "L4")

bb
$L1
[1] 3

$L4
[1] 5
```

Now build a list that consists of two new lists and bb into one list, where bb is a level deeper.

```
cc <- list(c(1:3), c(4:6), bb)
names(cc) <-  c("firstlist", "2ndlist", "LofL")

cc
$firstlist
[1] 1 2 3

$`2ndlist`
[1] 4 5 6

$LofL
$LofL$L1
[1] 3

$LofL$L4
[1] 5
```

I would now like to flatten the list "bb" that I've named "LofL" in this example.

My desired output is below.

```
ccdesired <- list(c(1:3), c(4:6), 3, 5)
names(ccdesired) <- c("firstlist", "2ndlist", "L1", "L4")

ccdesired
$firstlist
[1] 1 2 3

$`2ndlist`
[1] 4 5 6

$L1
[1] 3

$L4
[1] 5
```

Obviously I constructed ccdesired by hand, but I would like to know if there is a function or code to flatten the list titled "LofL" so that it is structured like ccdesired while maintaining names.  The function "flatten" is an obvious choice, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: To clarify, flatten does work just fine.  But I'd like to retain the rest of the list of list and just flatten the embedded list to be on the same level as the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a not-so-elegant solution:

```
bb <- list(3,5)
names(bb) <-  c("L1", "L4")
cc <- list(c(1:3), c(4:6), bb)
names(cc) <-  c("firstlist", "2ndlist", "LofL")
cc
#> $firstlist
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $`2ndlist`
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> $LofL
#> $LofL$L1
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> $LofL$L4
#> [1] 5

x <- list()
for(i in 1:length(cc))
  x <- c(x, if (is.list(cc[[i]])) unlist(cc[[i]]) else cc[i])
x
#> $firstlist
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $`2ndlist`
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> $L1
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> $L4
#> [1] 5
```